# how to call modalPopup from custom validator code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

i just want to show User friendly messages with using custom validator and modal popup extender.

here is my design :

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server"
TargetControlID="hdValue"
PopupControlID="Panelalert"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground1"
DropShadow="true" 
CancelControlID="btncancel">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>                                                                                    

<asp:Panel ID="Panelalert" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Width="233px" style = "display:none">

<div class="sidesection_top" style="float: left; height: 15px;" align="left">
<div style="float: left; width: 192px; height: 15px;" align="left">
Registration Alert</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 32px; height: 15px;" align="right">
<asp:ImageButton ID="Imgbtnclose" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/Close_button.jpg" BorderWidth="0px" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
<span id="lblalertmsg"><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
</div>
<div align="right" style="padding-right: 10px; height: 25px;">
<asp:Button ID="OkButton" runat="server" Text="Continue" CssClass="button"/>&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="button"/><br>
</div>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

here is my code :

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
     {
        using(DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var query = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(txtusername.Text.Trim())).Select(x => x).SingleOrDefault();
            if (query == null)
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MPE.Show();
                Label5.Text = "UserID Already Exist.";
                OkButton.Visible = false;
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

how ever i check it debugging it's calling this function how ever modal pop up not showing at front side.

please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Your markup and code looks OK. Do you get any JavaScript errors in the browser console ?

Have you checked to make sure you've included this in your page: -

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```